# React MUI Datatables - merge rows if they have the same value

Tags: reactjs, database, material-ui

certain rows from my database contain the same values expect time. How to marge them together that my table shows me the last of them and the rest of the rows ?

Example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dURTZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `.filter()` method to filter the (almost) duplicates out of your array before passing it to the MUI Datatable.